# Filter action not render user interface

Tags: reactjs, filter, redux, visibility

I have issue with my Filter. I have 2 buttons that filter cards. But when i go to my page with filter i have this problem:

> Uncaught Error: Given action "SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER", reducer "visibilityFilter" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

Here is my code:

Products.js

```
import Filter from '../filter/Filter';

class Products extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAdvert();
    this.props.setVisibilityFilter();
}

renderProducts = ({filteredAdverts}) => {
    if (filteredAdverts) {
        return filteredAdverts.map(product => {
            return (
                <Card key={product.id} advertItem={product}/>
            )
        })
    }
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <h2>Products</h2>
                 <Filter/>
                 <div className="products__card-box mb-3">
                    {this.renderProducts(this.props.filteredAdverts)}
                </div>
        </div>
}
```

Filter.js

```
import FilterLink from './FilterLink';
import {SHOW_ALL, SHOW_STONES, SHOW_PANELS} from "../../actions/types";

const Filter = () => (
<div className="btn-group" role="group">
    <FilterLink filter={SHOW_STONES}>
        Stones
    </FilterLink>

    <FilterLink filter={SHOW_PANELS}>
        Panels
    </FilterLink>
</div>
);

export default Filter;
```

FilterLink.js **UPDATE**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../../actions/filter';

const FilterLink = ({active, children, onClick}) => {

if(active) {
    return <button>{children}</button>
}

return (
    <button
        className="btn advert__btn"
        onClick={onClick}
        disabled={active}
    >
        {children}
    </button>
)};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
   active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
conslo.log(ownProps.filter);
return {
onClick: () => {
  dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter));
},};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FilterLink);
```

actions/filter.js

```
import {SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER} from "./types";

export const setVisibilityFilter = (filter) => ({
 type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER,
 filter
});
```

filter_reducer.js

```
import {SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, SHOW_STONES} from "../actions/types";
const visibilityFilter = (state = SHOW_STONES, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
        return action.filter;
    default:
        return state;
}};

export default visibilityFilter;
```

getVisibleProducts.js **UPDATE**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
import {SHOW_PANELS, SHOW_STONES, SHOW_ALL} from "../../actions/types";
const getVisibilityFilter = state => state.visibilityFilter;
const getAdverts = state => state.advert;

export const getVisibleProducts = createSelector(
[getVisibilityFilter, getAdverts],
(visibilityFilter, advert) => {
    console.log(advert);
      switch (visibilityFilter) {
          case SHOW_ALL:
              return advert;
          case SHOW_PANELS:
              return advert.filter(function(adv) {
                  return adv.title.includes('3d')
              });
          case SHOW_STONES:
              return advert.filter((adv) => {
                  return adv.title.includes('Декоративный')
              });
          default:
              throw new Error('Unknown filter ' + visibilityFilter);
}
});
```

**UPDATE**
console.log(advert) show me array with all my products, but when i add console.log(ownProps.filter) inpector says me:

> Uncaught Error: Unknown filter undefined
>
> getVisibleProducts.js array with products(consloe.log(advert)) undefined too.

I would be very grateful for any help in solving this problem. I tried many solutions, but none did not help me. I do not know what to do... Thanks for 
attention.

Comment: check the initial values of `SHOW_ALL, SHOW_STONES, SHOW_PANELS`, also do `console.log('ownProps', ownProps.filter)` and check its value

Comment: Presumably `SHOW_STONES` is not defined. You have not shared the code from `actions/types.js`, so we only have to guess here. Questions seeking help debugging must contain a [mcve]. You might have to rewrite your code to make a example that is both minimal and complete.

Comment: Dear Mayank Shukla, i update my code, i grateful u for any help. When i check ownProps.filter my array with products will be stay undefined.